# Conjugate replacement principle?

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm looking for name of a theorem or principle in complex numbers which says something like the following, "Any algebraic expression can be replaced with its value in conjugate if every variable or constant is also replaced by its conjugate.". Proof is essentially because i and -i are arbitrarily chosen, and you can swap them without any loss of generality.

Corollaries:

1. $(\bar{z^n}) = (\bar{z})^n$
2. Conjugate root theorem. If $(a + bi)$ is a root of a real polynomial, then $(a-bi)$ is also a root. Because if you replace everything with its conjugate expression doesn't change.

Sample Applications:

1. If $a$ is non-zero real number then $a^i$ has modulo 1. Proof:
   \begin{align}
   y &= a^i \\
   \bar{y} &= a^{-i} \\
   \|y\|^2 &= y \bar{y} \\ &= a^{i-i} \\ &= a^0 \\ &= 1
   \end{align}
2. $i^i$ is a real number, Proof:
   \begin{align}
   y &= i^i \\
   \bar{y} &= {(-i)}^{-i} \\&= \left(\frac{1}{i}\right)^{-i}\\&=i^i \\&=y
   \end{align}

I can go on with several examples, but I assume the point is clear. I am looking for the name of the principle, and a more precise statement of the same.

Comment: Fair enough for the question "what's $a^i$ when $a\in\Bbb R$". What's $i^i$?

Comment: Since $i = e^{i \pi / 2}$, when $i^i = e^{-\pi/2}$

Comment: Ah, ok. Because $i=e^{5i\pi/2}$ too. And $i=e^{9i\pi/2}$ as well.

Comment: Sure, you could definite along its principal arg, and norm. Point is if it can be well defined the statement holds.  The question is not about the specific applications I mentioned.

Comment: You can also define i^i as set of all possible values, like a multivalued thing if you want. Like a set, then statement would be it is a set of real numbers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your principle is formalized by the properties of the conjugation map $c \colon \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ given by $c(z) = \overline{z}$. Namely, what one needs to know is that $c$ is an anti-linear ring isomorphism with $c(x) = x$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then:

1. We have $\overline{z^n} = c(z^n) = c(\underbrace{z \cdot \ldots \cdot z}_{n \text{ times}}) = c(z) \cdot \ldots \cdot c(z) = \overline{z}^n. $
2. If $p = a_0 + a_1 X + \dots + a_n X^n \in \mathbb{R}[X]$ is a real polynomial with $p(z) = 0$ then 
   $$ p(\overline{z}) = p(c(z)) = a_0 + a_1 c(z) + \dots + a_n c(z)^n = c(a_0 + a_1 z + \dots + a_n z^n) = c(p(z)) = c(0) = 0.$$
3. Assume $a > 0$. Then $a^i$ is defined as $e^{i \ln(a)}$ and

$$ c(a^i) = c \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(i \ln(a))^n}{n!} \right) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(c(i) c(\ln(a))^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-i \ln(a))^n}{n!} = e^{-i \ln (a)} = a^{-i}.$$

Comment: Well it is not my principle, the fact that i and -i can simply be swapped sounds like common sense in an entire expression WLOG. I know it can be proved rigourously for the specific applications I mentioned. Im also not asking if it can be generalized to any isomorphism. I was just asking if this principle has any name associated with it?

Comment: I was suggesting that your principle is more or less to the statement that if you have an algebraic expression $p(z_1,\dots,z_n)$ where $p \in \mathbb{C}[X_1,\dots,X_n]$ then the conjugate of this expression is $\overline{p(z_1,\dots,z_n)} = \overline{p}(\overline{z_1},\dots,\overline{z_n})$ and the name of this principle is "conjugation is a ring isomorphism". I have no idea how else one should interpret "any algebraic expression can be replaced with its value in conjugate"...